# preg_match('/^\d*$/', $nr_procedimento) ? 'f' : 't'; - o que faz ? php

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Eu tenho isso (`preg_match('/^\d*$/', $nr_procedimento) ? 'f' : 't';`) em um código, mas eu não faço idéia do que faz, mais precisamente a parte do `preg_match('/^\d*$/'`. Alguém sabe?

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `preg_match` faz um match de uma expressão regular em uma string, retornando `1` em caso match, `0` se não deu match e `false` em caso algum erro tenha ocorrido.

Você passa dois parâmetros para ela, sendo o primeiro uma expressão regular e o segundo a string a ser veriricada.

No seu caso a regex é `/^\d*$/`, definindo cada parte:

> / indica o inicio da expressão regular
>
> ^ indica que seu padrão inicia da seguinte maneira
>
> \d define que são valores numéricos
>
> * define que o elemento anterior pode ocorrer **0** ou **n** vezes
>
> $ indica que sua string deve terminar aqui
>
> / indica o término da expressão regular

Pode ver mais sobre `preg_match` [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php).

---

Em seu exemplo completo você possui um [ternário](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria).

```
preg_match('/^\d*$/', $nr_procedimento) ? 'f' : 't';
```

Neste caso, se o conteúdo da variável `$nr_procedimento` der match na regex apresentada, o valor `f` será retornado pelo ternário, caso contrário sera retornado `t`.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que é uma instrução *inline* que vai retornar **f** ou **t** - o modo feio para *FALSE* ou *TRUE*. Só comentei aqui como observação, pois você deu o output da função, e ele terá algo diferente de `0` ou `1`.

Comment: Huum bá legal, obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Bem citado @PapaCharlie, vou editar e acrescentar isto. Acabei por explicar apenas o `preg_match` pois foi o que ele pediu na descrição da pergunta, mas o título induz ao resto.

Answer (score 1):

É uma [expressão regular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) para buscar uma linha que começe e termine com números.
Os simbolos amontoados são conhecidos como [meta caracteres](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php), cada um tem uma função:

`^` - siginifica inicio de linha.

`\d` - é uma abreviação para [0-9] ou seja apenas números.

`*` - torna a combinação gulosa, caso o maior número de vezes possível o padrão definido.

`$` - significa fim de linha